# Rails taking an insane amount of time to render page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

This is more of a "where do I start" question. The views appear to be taking the most time. I use slim and coffeescript, but what's confusing is why for async json requests, view rendering still takes wayy long.

responding to html (2205ms):

```
Started GET "/message_boards?pp=full-backtrace" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-06-14 19:56:24 +0000
Processing by MessageBoardsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"pp"=>"full-backtrace"}
  User Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  MessageBoard::Message Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `message_board_messages`.* FROM `message_board_messages`  ORDER BY `message_board_messages`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
   (3.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message_board_messages`
  Rendered message_boards/index.html.slim within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Exchange Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  `exchanges`.* FROM `exchanges`  ORDER BY `exchanges`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.3ms)  SELECT  `exchanges`.* FROM `exchanges`  ORDER BY `exchanges`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.slim (322.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2205ms (Views: 2026.9ms | ActiveRecord: 16.2ms)
```

responding to async json request (350ms)

```
Started GET "/message_boards.json?page=2" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-06-14 19:56:58 +0000
Processing by MessageBoardsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
  User Load (4.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  MessageBoard::Message Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  `message_board_messages`.* FROM `message_board_messages`  ORDER BY `message_board_messages`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20
   (2.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message_board_messages`
Completed 200 OK in 358ms (Views: 140.5ms | ActiveRecord: 13.5ms)
```

controller code (very simple):

```
class MessageBoardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize!(:follow, :message_board)
    @events = MessageBoard::Message.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
    gon.events = @events.as_json
    gon.total_items = @events.total_count

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {events: @events, total_items: @events.total_count} }
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
div ng-controller='MessageBoardController' ng-init='init()'
  .row
    .search-message-board
      h3.small-16.columns.medium-6.columns.left Showing {{ filteredEvents.length }} of {{ totalItems }} Results
      div.small-16.medium-6.columns.right
        form.search-form
          input.radius.search-text maxlength="120" type="text" ng-model='search' placeholder='Search'
          span.searchclear.fi-x-circle ng-click="search = ''"
  #messages
    .message-panel.radius ng-repeat='event in filteredEvents = (events | filter: search)'
      p
        strong ID:
        |  {{ event.id }}

      p
        strong Event:
        |  {{ event.title }}
      p
        strong Message:
        |  {{ event.body }}
      p
        strong Timestamp:
        |  {{ event.created_at }}

  pagination page="currentPage" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
```

here's a link to my [development.rb](https://gist.github.com/daino3/693ccb0d2d9ea39434d7183be51fffe5) - yes `assets.debug` is set to false

Comment: Show us your views, the logs say most of the time is spent there and that will explain the difference between HTML and JSON

Comment: @Leito - updated. The angular controller is not much other than setting the events which are ng-repeated through. But like I said, even in JSON requests, view rendering is taking forever.

Comment: Maybe is because you are dumping all events inside `gon.events`, it might be the size of that, how are you serializing @events into JSON? Is `total_count` your own method?

Comment: First, just an advice, do not order by `created_at` but use `id` instead. Second, I see that you are using AngularJS, and I suspect that the slowness issue could be on that side.

Comment: Looks like something I did fixed the majority of json response time (not sure what). But I implemented both of your feedback recs - id sorting and moved `gon.events` into the `format.html` block. Seems like `gon` might be a bottleneck. I'm using kaminari for paginating (total_count). Response time is down to `Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 35.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)`... still seems a little sluggish (for json response).